# Pass ownership of std::vector<std::unique_ptr<T>> to class constructor

Tags: c++, constructor

An existing factory method generates `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<MyType>>`

I want to pass this into the constructor of a new class which will take ownership of the objects, so the vector's elements are destroyed at class object destruction.

```
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<MyType>> vec = ...;
std::unique_ptr<MyClass> mc = new MyClass(vec);
return mc;

class MyClass
{
 public:
  MyClass(std::vector<std::unique_ptr<MyType>> &vec)
  {
    // ???????
  }

 private:
  std::vector<std::unique_ptr<MyType>> m_vec;
};
```

But clearly the original `vec` 'owns' the `MyType` objects and they will be destroyed.

What is the best way to change this? I don't really want to move away from `unique_ptr` and I want to make it clear to future developers that `MyClass` is the owner of the vector.

Comment: `MyClass(std::vector<std::unique_ptr<MyType>> vec)` + `m_vec(std::move(vec))` and `std::make_unique<MyClass>(std::move(vec));`?

Comment: W/o showing the usage, the question unlikely can be answered. The description is very vague, a usage code would make it more clear. You can move each vector element into a new vector, you can move the entire vector...

Comment: Do you really want to move a vector into MyClass or do you want a constructor that can create multiple instances of MyType. And if so do all the instances need the same constructor arguments or different ones for each instance?

Answer (score 6):

The simplest way is likely to mimic what a *move constructor* does and use an rvalue reference:

```cpp
class MyClass {
public:
    MyClass(std::vector<std::unique_ptr<MyType>>&& vec)
//                                              ^^
        : m_vec(std::move(vec)) {}
//              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

private:
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<MyType>> m_vec;
};
```

You can now move such a `vector` into `MyClass`:

```cpp
int main() {
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<MyType>> vec;

    MyClass mc(std::move(vec));
}
```

---

If you aren't familiar with *move semantics*, here's an example of what it can be used for. Also see [The rule of five](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three) for details.

```cpp
class MemoryHog {
public:
    // default ctor, hogging a lot of memory:
    MemoryHog() : m_ptr(new char[1024 * 1024 * 1024]) {}

    // copy ctor, hogging memory and copies:
    MemoryHog(const MemoryHog& other) : m_ptr(new char[1024 * 1024 * 1024]) {
        std::copy_n(other.m_ptr, 1024 * 1024 * 1024, m_ptr);
    }

    // move ctor, doesn't allocate but instead steals the pointer from the
    // object being moved from:
    MemoryHog(MemoryHog&& other) noexcept :
        m_ptr(std::exchange(other.m_ptr, nullptr)) {}

    // copy assignment operator + move assignment operator be here too

    ~MemoryHog() {
        delete[] m_ptr;
    }

private:
    char* m_ptr;
};
```

Comment: I'm behind the times as an old-school c++ dev... move ctors are not really familiar to me - thanks!

Comment: @Mr.Boy It's the new cool thing since C++11 :-) [move constructors](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/move_constructor)  and [Value categories](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_category) may be of interest

Comment: @Mr.Boy I added a small example of how new classes can be written to make use of move semantics.

Comment: @Mr.Boy: Move constructors (and move assignment) are what fixed all the problems of `std::auto_ptr` (giving us `std::unique_ptr`)